# Python paramiko SSH nothing returned when blocked by dialog

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using paramiko to ssh into a server and then from this server ssh into another one just to get the fingerprint, so I'd like to see the message that asks if I want to accept that fingerprint or no.

I'm using this code:

```
    stdin,stdout,stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(command)
    outlines = stdout.readlines()
    resp = ''.join(outlines)
    return resp
```

but it returns me nothing. I think it's because at some point the ssh command wait for me to input yes/no if I want to accept the fingerprint. I did `man ssh` and didn't find a way to automatically answer `no` for this question.

I've found this: [Reading output of Top command using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101619/reading-output-of-top-command-using-paramiko) which teaches how to invoke a shell. But what if I want to receive the text just up to the stopping point?

Comment: What is in the command variable?

Comment: @AdamKerz it's just ssh hostname